# Dockerfile php-fpm unmet dependencies

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile in which to build a container for php-fpm. I pulled in my base ubuntu image and it gets to work but then exits when trying to install php-fpm and php5-intl due to unmet dependencies.

[image]

Can anyone check over my file and spot anything obvious please :)

```
FROM phalcon/ubuntu

MAINTAINER bob <bob@bob.com>

RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Install software requirements
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5 && \
add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable && \
apt-get update -y --force-yes && \
apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes && \
BUILD_PACKAGES="supervisor php5-fpm git php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-pgsql php5-mongo php5-dev pwgen" && \
apt-get -y --force-yes install $BUILD_PACKAGES && \
apt-get remove --purge -y software-properties-common && \
apt-get autoremove -y && \
apt-get clean && \
apt-get autoclean

# Add PHP config.
ADD php-fpm.conf /etc/php-fpm.conf

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/etc/php-fpm.d", "/var/log/php-fpm", "/srv/http"]

# Define entrypoint.
ENTRYPOINT ["php-fpm"]

# Expose ports.
EXPOSE 9000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some issue regarding the use of the source image `phalcon/ubuntu` from what I can see.

There's actually no reason to build your own PHP-FPM image, as official ones are supplied: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ This way you can select the exact PHP version you want to use.

Just for kicks, here is the repository from which the image is built (PHP 5.6): https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/5.6/fpm